# I'm running an application from a .bat file. How do I make the window scroll up and down?

Tags: batch-file

My Java application runs from this .bat file

```
@ECHO OFF
mode con:cols=130 lines=60
CLS
java -cp lib\postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc4.jar;bin telecom.cli.Telecom
PAUSE
```

A Window opens, the app runs smoothly...  But I can't scroll Up and Down.
What do I need to add to this .bat file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simple answer is that the lines parameter can be set to a large value which will create a larger than normal window which will be scrollable.

> 

The happy answer is that the mode command is not required. Simply create a shortcut. In the shortcut Properties\Layout set the Screen buffer size (Width: 130, Height: {maximum 9999}), Window Size (Width: 130, Height: {25 for example})
This will create a window 130*25 and the buffered contents (up to a maximum of 9999 lines) will be scrollable.